# Why the radius of convergence and not "areas of convergence" for power series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

My calculus is quite rusty and I'm trying to rebuild it on an intuitive basis. Currently, I am looking at power series and have trouble understanding the radius of convergence.

I am comfortable with the fact that if the limit of the function at a certain point $a$ doesn't exist, the power series won't converge for this value of $x$. But why can't the series converge for $x$ whose absolute value is greater than this point? Why aren't there "areas of convergence" instead of a single radius of convergence?

Comment: For a series of functions, convergence can, indeed, happen on complicated sets.  But for a power series, convergence happens in a disk (in the complex plane).  Your textbook should explain this with its discussion of power series.

Comment: One of these non-disc examples is Dirichlet series: $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n^s}$, you have an *abscissa of convergence*, which means a set of values $\{ s : \Re(s)> a \}$ (e.g. the Riemann zeta function has $s=1$). The other main example is Laurent series, which are basically power series in both $z$ and $1/z$, and can converge in an annulus.

Comment: Thanks! Just checking: the convergence can't happen on a disconnected set, can it?

Comment: In fact, set theory was created by Cantor in response to questions about the domain of convergence of *Fourier series*, which can be a set that is a lot nastier than an interval. The domain of convergence of a power series (on the real line) is always an interval.

Comment: Could you link to an easy example of a series which behaves quite different from power series here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assume the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges for some $z\in{\mathbb C}$. Then it converges absolutely for any $z'$ that is nearer to the origin than $z$; see the proof below.

From this fact it follows by mere logic, that when the series *diverges* at some $z\in{\mathbb C}$ it *cannot* converge at any point $z''$ farther away from the origin.

*Proof.* When $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges at $z$ then there is an $M$ with $\left|a_kz^k\right|\leq M$ for all $k$. Assume now that $0\leq r<\left|z\right|$. Then $q:={r\over\left|z\right|}<1$ and
$$\left|a_k\right|r^k=q^k\left|a_k z^k\right|\leq Mq^k\qquad(k\geq0)\ .$$
It follows that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left|a_k\right|r^k$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of Abel's lemma, which is the basis for analytic functions:

*Abel's lemma. –* If $r_0$ is positive real number such that the *sequence* $(\lvert a_n\rvert r_0^n)$ is bounded from above, then the *series* $\sum a_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent for $\lvert z\rvert<r_0$.

Hence if $R=\sup\bigl\{\lvert z\rvert\:;\: \sum a_nz^n\enspace\text{converges}\bigr\}$, the series converges if $\lvert z\rvert<R$ and trivially diverges if $\lvert z\rvert>R$.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that the series $\sum_{i=0}^na_n$ is convergent in the usual sense then certainly the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded (it must even converge to$~0$); it follows that for any $z\in\Bbb C$ with $|z|<1$ the series $\sum_{i=0}^na_nz^n$ is absolutely convergent, and therefore convergent. This can then be applied to the situation where a power series $\sum_{i=0}^na_nx^n$ converges for $x$ equal some particular complex value$~z_0\neq0$; it *automatically* also converges for any $x=zz_0$ with $|z|<1$, that is, whenever $|x|<|z_0|$. This easily implies that the domain of convergence of any (formal) power series, if not equal to$\{0\}$ or to$~\Bbb C$, is the interior of a disk centred at$~0$, plus some subset of the boundary of that disk.

Answer (score 2):

For power series, the area of convergence really is the interior of a circle, perhaps with some points on the boundary. Here is a quote from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, second edition (also called *Baby Rudin*), page 60, referring to power series of the complex number $z$.

> More specifically, with every power series there is associated a
>   circle, the circle of convergence, such that (19) converges if $z$ is
>   in the interior of the circle and diverges of $z$ is in the exterior
>   (to cover all cases, we have to consider the plane as the interior of
>   a circle of infinite radius, and a point as a circle of radius zero).
>   The behavior on the circle of convergence is much more varied and
>   cannot be described so simply.

Rudin then continues to prove various convergence tests, such as the power and ratio tests, that give a radius of convergence.

@GEdgar, in his comment, points out that other series of functions can give a convergence region other than a circle, but your question is about power series.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in this case, an example is worth more than a detailed answer.  Consider the power series
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i2^i}x^i
$$
(this is $\log(1+x/2)$ for $|x|<2$).

Now, apply the ratio test (but keep the $x$) to get
$$
\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{(i+1)2^{i+1}}x^{i+1}}{\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i2^i}x^i}\right|=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{i}{2(i+1)}\right||x|.
$$

The limit of this is $\frac{|x|}{2}$.

Now, we know that the ratio test converges when this limit is less than 1, this only happens when $\frac{|x|}{2}<1$ or that $|x|<2$.  This is your interval of convergence.

In general, for power series, if you try this with either the ratio or the root tests (in this generality, you often use the $\limsup$ instead of the limit), you get a value from the coefficients and your $|x|$ must be small enough so that the series passes the test; if $|x|$ is not small enough, that test says that the series diverges - it's the greater than 1 or the less than 1 in those tests that tell you that there is only one region where the series converges.